# Getting Variables Passed In URL Laravel

Tags: url, laravel, uri, laravel-4

Probably a basic question but I can't seem to get it.

I am wanting to grab the variable in my url to my controller.

// index view

```
@foreach ($paymentInfos as $p)
        <tr>
             <td><a href="{{ URL::action('AdminController@getPackingSlip', array('order_id' => $p->order_id)) }}"> {{ $p->order_id }}</a></td>
             <td>{{ $p->lastname }} {{ $p->firstname }}</td>
             <td>{{ $p->buyer_email }}</td>
        </tr> 
      @endforeach
```

// route

```
Route::get('printpackingslip', 'AdminController@getPackingSlip');
```

// Controller

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getPackingSlip()
    {

        $rules = array('order_id' => 'order_id');


        return View::make('admin.packingslip')->with($rules);
    }
}
```

When you click on the link it goes to www.domain.com/printpackingslip?order_id=3

I do not know how to grab the order_id=3 in my controller.

Also would I be better off using the :(num) to generate a URI of /printpackingslip/3 or does it not matter?

For example:

// in my first view have:

```
<td><a href="{{ URL::to('printpackingslip', array('order_id' => $p->order_id)) }}"> {{ $p->order_id }}</a></td>
```

// then my route:

```
Route::get('printpackingslip/(:num)', 'AdminController@getPackingSlip');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this Laravel 4? Let's review it all:

Route:

```
Route::get('printpackingslip/{order_id}', 'AdminController@getPackingSlip');
```

Controller:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function getPackingSlip($order_id)
    {
        return "you selected $order_id";
    }
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($paymentInfos as $p)
   ...
   <td><a href="{{ URL::route('printpackingslip', array('order_id' => $p->order_id)) }}"> {{ $p->order_id }}</a></td>
   ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Brilliant! It seems so simple once I see it... Thanks again!