# How to pass two parameter using <a href=""> way in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, parameter-passing

I already saw the Question [Getting Variables Passed In URL Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056484/getting-variables-passed-in-url-laravel)

I can't follow that because i am loading the url in the tiny box.

**I need to send two parameters to route using**

And i should able to get the values in the views by `(array('RoleID' => $data))->get();`

How can i make it possible another varialble i.e., `$role->StaffID`

```
<a class=\"edit\" onClick=\"TINY.box.show({url:\'staffsrights/".trim($user->RoleID)."\',animate:true,openjs:opennewjs1()})\">Right</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I tried

```
<a class=\"edit\" onClick=\"TINY.box.show({url:\'staffsrights/".trim($user->RoleID,$usertwo->StaffID)."\',animate:true,openjs:opennewjs1()})\">Right</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Here is the route :

```
Route::get('staffsrights/{data}', 'StaffsController@staffsrights');
```

How can i do this ??

Comment: How does your route look like?

Comment: Route::get('staffsrights/{data}', 'StaffsController@staffsrights');

Comment: Do you want to pass the values in kind of a key/value thing or just values?